# How do I get the span ID to the <script> tag in ejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, ejs

I'm working a chatbox system where I would like the push the scroller down to the last entry of the chat;

What I currently have is `<span id="message-<%-i-%>">` for each message id shown below

But I can't seem to figure out how to get the number from the span to the `<script>...</script>` component.

*Please Note: This html is Embedded JavaScript*

#### Show Messages

```html
<div id="showMessages" class="flex-container">
    <%  for (var i = docs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {%>
    <span id="message-<%-i%>">
        <small>From <%= docs[i].from %> | <%= docs[i].time %></small><br><b><span title="<%=userinfo.id%>"><%= docs[i].nick %></span> said: <%= docs[i].msg %></b><br><br>
        <% } %>
    </span>
</div>
```

#### Scroll Script

```html
<script>
    function scrollToFirstMsg() {
        const messages = document.getElementById('showMessages');
        const messageid = document.getElementById('message-');
        messages.scrollTop = messageid.offsetTop - 10;
    }
    scrollToFirstMsg();
    setInterval(scrollToFirstMsg, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: <%=i%> not -i for I’d